# How to use several pointers to one twodimensional array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion

I want to create pointers on array in c. For example, I have an array

```
char arr1[4][20];
```

I want to make pointers and these pointers would get memory like this pointer p = arr1[0][0-20]
t = arr1[1][0-20], u = arr[1][0-20]. I want to keep all strings from different files in one array.
I try to do something like that, but it's not working.

```
char name[20][20];
char *s[20];
char *t[20];
s = name[1];
t = name[2];
```

Comment: `char (*myptr)[20];` creates a *pointer-to-array* of `char [20]`. Then `myptr = name;` Or `char *s = name[1];` and `char *t = name[2];`. In the case of `myptr`, you will have `myptrr[0]` points to `name[0]`, and `myptr[1]` to `name[1]` and so on. In the case of `s` and `t`, they are pointers to the individual chars in `name[1]` and `name[2]`.

Comment: do you want to connect pointer to array rows??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array declared like this

```
char name[20][20];
```

used in expressions as for example an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its firs element that is has the type `char ( * )[20]`.

So you may write for example

```
char ( *s )[20] = name;
```

In this case for example to traverse character elements of the array pointed to by the pointer s you need to use expressions like

```
( *s )[0], ( *s )[1], an so on
```

Or like

```
s[0][0], s[0][1], and so on.
```

It will be simpler to traverse pointed character arrays if pointer would be declared like

```
char *s = name[0];
char *t = name[1];
```

and so on.

So either you should declare pointers like

```
char ( *s )[20] = name;
char ( *t )[20] = name + 1;
```

or like

```
char *s = name[0];
char *t = name[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you declare a pointer to an array of 20 elements:

```
char (*ptr)[20];
```

So, this is how you do what you want to do:

```
char name[20][20];
char (*s)[20] = &name[1]; // note the &
char (*t)[20] = &name[2];
```

And here's how you access elements of those arrays later on:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*s); ++i) {
  printf("%d ", (*s)[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round out you question with a short exercise putting the pointer assignments to use. For example continuing from the comment above, with the creation of `myptr` as a *pointer-to-aray* of `char[20]` and `s` and `t` to an array of `char[20]`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    const char name[20][20] = { "Mickey Mouse", "Minnie Mouse", "Pluto",
                                "Bugs Bunny", "Porky Pig", "Daffy Duck", "" },
                (*myptr)[20] = name;

    while (1) {
        const char *s = *myptr++, *t = *myptr++;

        if (*s)
            puts (s);
        else
            break;

        if (*t)
            puts (t);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2arrexercise
Mickey Mouse
Minnie Mouse
Pluto
Bugs Bunny
Porky Pig
Daffy Duck
```

Question: What purpose does the empty-string serve as the last element of `name` in the code above?